# Não consigo receber token da aplicação, help!

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, oauth

## Seguem minhas classes de segurança da aplicação;

## Classe OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt

```
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{   
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("angular").
        secret(passwordEncoder().encode("@ngul@r0"))
        .scopes("read", "write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").accessTokenValiditySeconds(300)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 12); //na sua implemetação so tira o refresh_token    
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("secret");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

## Classe WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterCustom

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterCustom extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/categorias").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/categorias");
    }

}
```

## Clase CustomTokenEnhancer

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("organization", " Token Custom ");
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

## Classe WebMvcConfig

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
}
```

Erro ao tentar buscar um token com a requisição abaixo:

[image: Falha ao buscar token]

## Erro do servidor:

```
2020-03-24 11:17:32.963  INFO 10716 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:416) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode estar acontecendo por que alguma outra aplicação está tentando enviar algo na porta da sua aplicação (8080). Se estiver usando windows rode o seguinte comando no terminal para listar as aplicações usando a porta `netstat -a -n -o | findstr <porta>` (Altere o  para a porta que deseja localizar) depois rode `Taskkill /PID <pid> /F` (Alterar o  pelo número do PID que foi encontrado na listagem do comando do netstat).